# Future class error - First error: Argument cannot be null

Tags: apex, rest-api, controller, custom-controller, post

I have a requirement where I need to send JWT token as a part of my request body.
I have created a JWT class and an Apex rest class to acheive the required scenario.
Below are the classes

Apex Rest Class:

```
  public class AccUpdateController {
        @future(callout=true)
        public static void AccupdateController(Set<Id> accountIdset) { 
JWT jwt = new JWT();
        String token = jwt.issue();       
            string resultBodyGet = '';

            list<Account> accts = [SELECT Unique_ID__c, Account_Status__c, Email__c from Account where Account_Partner_Status__c = 'ACTIVE' and Id IN:accountIdset];

            system.debug('>>>>>>>>>>' + accts);        
            for(Account c : accts){         

                MAp<String, String> tags = new Map<String, String>();
                tags.put('accId', c.Unique_ID__c);
                tags.put('email', c.Email__c);
                tags.put('status', c.Account_Status__c); 
                tags.put('jwt token', token);
                system.debug('#### Input JSON: ' + JSON.serialize(tags));            
                try{
                    string endpoint = 'https://my-endpoint.com';
                    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
                    req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
                    req.setMethod('POST');
                    req.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
                    req.setbody(JSON.serialize(tags));
                    Http http = new Http();
                    system.debug('Sending User to update status');
                    HTTPResponse response = http.send(req); 
                    system.debug('Status updated');
                    resultBodyGet = response.getBody();
                    system.debug('Output response:' + resultBodyGet);
                    accResponse myAccResponse = new accResponse();
                    myAccResponse = (accResponse) JSON.deserialize(resultBodyGet, accResponse.class);
                    system.debug('#### myAccResponse: ' + myAccResponse);

                }
                catch (exception e) {                              
                }   
            }
        }    
        public class accResponse {
            public string message {get;set;}
        }
    }
```

Below is the JWT class

```
public class JWT {

    public jwt(){

    }

     String alg = 'RS256';
     String ISS = 'F360';
    String SUB = 'F360';
    String AUD = 'T360';
   Long expires_at = math.roundToLong(DateTime.now().addMinutes(10).getTime() / 1000);    
    Long issued_at = math.roundToLong(DateTime.now().addSeconds(-2).getTime() / 1000);
    public Map<String,String> claims {get;set;}
    //public Integer validFor {get;set;}
    public String cert {get;set;}
    public String pkcs8 {get;set;}
    string privatekey = 'XXXMyPrivatekeyXXX'


    public static final String HS256 = 'HS256';
    public static final String RS256 = 'RS256';
    public static final String NONE = 'none';


    public JWT(String alg) {
        this.alg = alg;
        //this.validFor = 300;
    }


    public String issue() {

        String jwt = '';

        JSONGenerator header = JSON.createGenerator(false);
        header.writeStartObject();
        header.writeStringField('alg', this.alg);
        header.writeEndObject();
        String encodedHeader = base64URLencode(Blob.valueOf(header.getAsString()));

        JSONGenerator body = JSON.createGenerator(false);
        body.writeStartObject();
        body.writeStringField('iss', this.iss);
        body.writeStringField('sub', this.sub);
        body.writeStringField('aud', this.aud);
        //Long rightNow = (dateTime.now().getTime()/1000)+1;
        body.writeNumberField('expires_at', this.expires_at);
        body.writeNumberField('issued_at', this.issued_at);
        if (claims != null) {
            for (String claim : claims.keySet()) {
                body.writeStringField(claim, claims.get(claim));
            }
        }
        body.writeEndObject();

        jwt = encodedHeader + '.' + base64URLencode(Blob.valueOf(body.getAsString()));

        if ( this.alg == HS256 ) {
            Blob key = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(privateKey);
            Blob signature = Crypto.generateMac('hmacSHA256',Blob.valueof(jwt),key);
            jwt += '.' + base64URLencode(signature);  
        } else if ( this.alg == RS256 ) {
            Blob signature = null;

            if (cert != null ) {
                signature = Crypto.signWithCertificate('rsa-sha256', Blob.valueOf(jwt), cert);
            } else {
                Blob privateKey = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(pkcs8);
                signature = Crypto.sign('rsa-sha256', Blob.valueOf(jwt), privateKey);
            }
            jwt += '.' + base64URLencode(signature);  
        } else if ( this.alg == NONE ) {
            jwt += '.';
        }

        return jwt;

    }


    public String base64URLencode(Blob input){ 
        String output = encodingUtil.base64Encode(input);
        output = output.replace('+', '-');
        output = output.replace('/', '_');
        while ( output.endsWith('=')){
            output = output.subString(0,output.length()-1);
        }
        return output;
    }


}
```

When I execute this class, I am recieving an error stating

> First error: Argument cannot be null.

Can anyone please suggest how to overcome this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the `pkcs8` variable in JWT class, it is null, because the JWT class is called from future context and it isn't set to any value.

Therefore, the method `Blob privateKey = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(pkcs8);` gets null as an argument which is unacceptable.

The same relates to `cert` variable.

Comment: Thanks @MariiaIllarinova....What do I need to call in the argument of private key in my code. Please suggest

Comment: Set it after ```JWT jwt = new JWT();``` and before ```String token = jwt.issue();``` directly in the future method.

Comment: Thanks a ton Mariia... :)